# Can we upload .mp3 files from the music library to a remote server?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to upload `.mp3` files (from **music library**) to a remote server, and I have successfully done so.

Now I just want to know if Apple will approve my app. I've read somewhere that the files in the music library are protected (copyrighted).

Comment: hi, I'm having the same dilemma, did Apple approved uploading music from the library?

Comment: apple approved or not? @maulik

Comment: @amitgupta: haven't checked

Comment: can u tell me the process to upload mp3 files to remote server? @Maulik

Comment: Hey @Maulik can you share the code for upload  mp3 on server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying is allowed as long as the music isn't shared — it must remain in personal space. And you must notify the user of everything, obviously.

But with Apple, you never know until you try it. :-p

Anyway, good luck! It seems interesting, so report back! :-D